# Why Can't PowerShell use this Copy-Item command without a Cannot Find File Error?

Tags: powershell

I am running into an issue with my local PC and trying to test a powershell script I am writing. I have had two co-workers try the exact same script and they are able to run it but mine runs into an error. Below is the commandset I am using:

```
`$file = "$env:userprofile\appdata\local\google\chrome\user data\default\bookmarks"
copy-item $file c:\temp`
```

No one else can replicate this and I have checked my executionpolicy which is the same as the others who have tried.

[Running Script Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIWL9.png)

Comment: Are you able to manually run (type out) `Copy-Item -LiteralPath 'c:\users\listdlv\appdata\local\google\chrome\user data\default\bookmarks'`?

Comment: I am not, it still gives me the cannot find item problem. It seems like it is permission-related but I can't figure out how or what would cause that to be the case :(

Comment: Can you run it as a normal user/not admin, or read the file/attributes like `Get-Item $file` or `Get-Content $file`?

Comment: I could use Get-Item $file in a non-elevated powershell prompt but Get-Content $file produced the cannot find file error again. I notice the Get-Item showed it in the OneDrive path.. which I am not sure if that is normal behavior for this?

Comment: It could be symlinked out to OneDrive, I see some people do that to sync it between browsers etc. Try checking the attributes like `(Get-Item $file).Attributes` or `gci $path -Force | select Fullname,LinkType,Target`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out it was something to do with the image on the PC I was using because it couldn't be replicated outside of it. The fix was reimaging and the permissions were restored. Thanks for everyone's help!